# RapidJson undefined reference

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, rapidjson

```
in function rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::GenericDocument(rapidjson::GenericDocument<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> > const&):

    error: undefined reference to 'rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> >::GenericValue(rapidjson::GenericValue<rapidjson::UTF8<char>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator> > const&)'
```

I am facing this error while using rapidjson library in cocos2dX.

Comment: show your proper code then may be i can help you. http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/14003

Comment: look i am creating json document using rapidjson in which i am adding member to doc using AddMember function but i got above error while compiling....

Answer (score 3):

This question was asked a while ago, recording the answer here for anyone else with the same problem.

If you are passing a `rapidjson::Document` into a function, try passing by reference. i.e. instead of `void doSomething(rapidjson::Document doc)` write `void doSomething(rapidjson::Document &doc)`. I think there is an issue with using the `rapidjson::Document` [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor).

Comment: Yes. Document/Value is non-copyable by design.

Answer (score 0):

deep copy not allowed,pleased use reference. such as

```
void parseJsonDocument(const char* data, rapidjson::Document& json);
const rapidjson::Value& itemValue = value["value"];
```